# Importing all predefined PHP classes to my namespace

Tags: php, oop

```
namespace externalServices\Service;
class FirstService  extends Exception {



}
```

now Exception  is not defined. I know I can do use \Exception AS Exception; But how can I import all native classes to the namespace

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: because i want to use the native classes in my code

Comment: You can use every native class you want, just add a \ to it. Like `new \DateTime()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't be done.

The solution is to either manually import...

```
use Exception; //Notice leading \ is not needed
```

Or use an absolute path...

```
class FirstService extends \Exception {
```